# Azure DevOps Pull Requests line colours

Tags: azure-devops

I created a PR and some of lines are marked with red or green colors (in newly created file). Cannot find what does it mean... anyone knows? Below is the example:
[image]

Comment: Hi Bart, could the updated answer resolves your original question. Would you mind [accepting it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) if it's helpful? So that more members can get useful info from marked answer and we can archive this thread for you. Thanks~

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Cannot find what does it mean... anyone knows?

The `Green` and `Red` colors are for [PR Code Coverage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops).

[image]

The lines marked in red indicates that your test can't reach those lines. (The code in else{} won't be executed, not covered)

The lines marked in green indicates that your test has run through those lines/code, covered.

Comment: I was pointed to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops

Comment: @Bart Sorry for the misunderstanding, answer updated. Hope it can be helpful for your issue :)