# Azure DevOps Pull Requests orange line with exclamation mark

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Almost answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845004/azure-devops-pull-requests-line-colours). Which directs us to the [code coverage for pull requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops) page.

[image: pr]

However, it doesn't say anywhere what this orange exclamation mark means.

Answer (score 2):

I've hunted high and low to find an article that describes what the orange line means but I'm unable to find an article to link to. Looking at the HTML/CSS elements on the page it is described as a warning.

Here is an example of when it was showing for me:

[image]

Looking at the tests I was reviewing, there were certain cases in the linq statement that were not being tested, e.g. when there is more than one lesson with the same name. After getting the other developer to add in this missing test it turned green.

From this, I can deduce that the orange warning will show when there are some test cases that haven't been covered in a block of code. Of course, there may be other reasons as well but this is one I've found.